# Linking errors when using Google Test

Tags: linker-errors, googletest

When I try to link against the Google Test library, I get the following errors:

```
1> msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in gtest.lib(gtest.obj)
1> msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in gtest.lib(gtest.obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that gtest has been built to use the same C Runtime Library (CRT) as your exe.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) for full information.

Currently gtest provides two .sln files; `gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest.sln` and `gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md.sln`.  The first uses the compiler flags `/MT` and `/MTd` for Release and Debug builds respectively (the static version of the CRT), while the second uses `/MD` and `/MDd` (the DLL version of the CRT).

You need to use the .sln which corresponds to your settings for these flags.